# Issues with MATLAB butter

Tags: matlab, butterworth

I am using MATLAB R2015 and cannot implement 'butter' without getting an error related to too many output arguments from the `polyfit` part of the script.  I have used the same implementation for years with other versions of MATLAB.

Example:

```
[b, a] = butter(2,[.15,.3]);
```

> Error using `poly`
>   Too many output arguments.
>
> Error in `zp2ss` (line 127)
>       `den = real(poly(p(i:i+1)));`
>
> Error in `butter` (line 97)
>   `[a,b,c,d] = zp2ss(z,p,k);`

I get the same error implementing the examples in the help documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess but is there any chance you've defined your own poly function? `which('poly')` should point to some Matlab directory unless you've defined it elsewhere, potentially as a variable?. For me on a newer version that path is something like `$MATLAB/toolbox/matlab/polyfun/poly.m` You can also edit the poly function `edit poly` and verify that there is one output argument for the function.

Also, I'd advise against ever writing decimal numbers without a leading zero. It took me way to long to figure out what `[.15,.3]` was. Instead write `[0.15,0.3]` or even just `[0.15 0.3]` **Edit:** I just realized that is an example in Matlab ... my point stands but the toolbox author should know better ...